# npm doesn't build Contextify Release - node path not found?

Tags: node.js, packaging, npm

I'm working on packaging a node app to be deployed on a server without npm. I believe I have it figured out - I used npm to install all the dependencies in a local node_modules folder according to a package.json file.

It all appears to work well, but when I attempt to run the node file from the server, it complains that it `Cannot find module '../build/Release/contextify'`.

That makes sense, because in `node_modules/.npm/contextify/0.0.4/package/lib/contextify.js`, it asks for the file in question, and `node_modules/.npm/contextify/0.0.4/package/build` has no directory called `Release`. I assumed that npm just hadn't built the release, so I switched back to the dev machine, and ran `npm install` - it didn't complain, and it appeared to build contextify:

```
$ sudo npm install

> contextify@0.0.4 preinstall /path/to/node/stuff/node_modules/contextify
> node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build

'clean' finished successfully (0.014s)
Setting srcdir to                        : /path/to/node/stuff/node_modules/.npm/contextify/0.0.4/package 
Setting blddir to                        : /path/to/node/stuff/node_modules/.npm/contextify/0.0.4/package/build 
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.4.5 
'configure' finished successfully (0.043s)
Waf: Entering directory `/path/to/node/stuff/node_modules/.npm/contextify/0.0.4/package/build'
[1/2] cxx: src/contextify.cc -> build/default/src/contextify_1.o
[2/2] cxx_link: build/default/src/contextify_1.o -> build/default/contextify.node
Waf: Leaving directory `/path/to/node/stuff/node_modules/.npm/contextify/0.0.4/package/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.370s)
```

unfortunately, the `package/build` directory still doesn't have a `Release` folder.

So, I guess the question is if contextify is failing to build because my node path isn't set (I tried `export NODE_PATH`, but it didn't seem to help...), or if there is some other reason that contextify doesn't appear to be building.

Maybe I'm missing something larger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too am having the same issue,

You may want to add the issue to github, the author may be able to help you sooner than on here. 
https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues?sort=created&direction=desc&state=closed&page=1

Answer (score 3):

The fix for this error is just to remove waf's "build" directory, then re-configure.  Somehow waf caches the bad config result due to a missing NODE_PATH, so even if you then remember and set it, it won't actually compile anything despite the configure reporting no errors.  Silly!

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/"
rm -fr build
node-waf configure
node-waf build
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your local version of nodejs is v.0.4.* and your server version of nodejs is v0.5.*

Make sure you use the same version of nodejs for dev and production. If you switch to v0.4.* I bet your problem will be solved. I noticed that the node-waf 'build' configuration is switched from 'default' to 'Release' somewhere in the 5.* versions.

One warning however:

Some npm packages are using (compiled) binaries. I.M.O, you should not bundle 'compiled' node_modules in one package to deploy it on a 'different' platform without npm. It's a matter of time before you will running into problems. (like the one above)

Comment: This [Node commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/879eb16280688436d791ebb79b05198ac4e4b038#diff-3) is causing the problems